# AOSP SystemService IPC Calls Threading

Tags: android, android-source

I'm trying to get a better understanding of how the threading works for IPC Calls, and SystemServices. Do IPC Calls from the Native to the Service get called on the main thread, using the looper, or is there another thread calling the methods in SystemService?

Comment: Depends on the API you're using.  To check you're looper, just call Looper.myLooper().

Comment: I'm just using the basic Proxy, and Stubs that are generated from the hidl.

Comment: I actually took your idea, and instead got the thread id from each method. It looked like it was using a thread pool for IPC calls because the ID is constantly changing. The AIDL documentation confirmed this. Thanks for the idea!

Comment: Yep, IPC does Thread pool management for you ;).